# Bootstrap Dist fails to load with Bower

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I'm new to Yeoman and Angular and am trying to build a dist package of my app.

Currently in development all the dependencies load as expected, but when I run Grunt and grunt serve:dist the application loads but it is not able to find the bootstrap.css file.  I have tried various different solutions such as:

1. Change the bower.json file to use bootstrap: '3.3.4' instead of version 3.3.5
2. Adding an overides object to the bower.json file as follows:

   ```
    "overrides":{
     "bootstrap":{
        "main":[
           "less/bootstrap.less",
           "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
           "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ]
     }
   ```

   }
3. I have tried both the bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css file in the index.html file as follows:

[image]

When I run the server the index.html file is looking to load the bootstrap file but gets the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 and the address is http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css.bootstrap.css

I have seen a bit of discussion about this problem online, but I have tried all the solutions suggested with no luck.

Can anybody shed any light on this?

It works fine in a development environmemt when I run grunt serve - but the problem arises in the production dist version.

Thanks

Linda